# Question regarding mapcon and its supposed equivalence to (apply #'nconc (maplist ...))

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcon) states that `mapcon` is (roughly?) equivalent to `(apply #'nconc (maplist ...))`, i.e. "the results of applying function are combined into a list by the use of nconc rather than list".

But if this

```
(maplist #'identity '(1 2 3)) ; '((1 2 3) (2 3) (3))
(apply #'nconc '((1 2 3) (2 3) (3)))
```

works, why doesn't this

```
(apply #'nconc (maplist #'identity '(1 2 3)))
(mapcon #'identity '(1 2 3))
```

work also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relationship is not "roughly" the same, it is defined exactly as:

```
(mapcon f x1 ... xn)
  ==  (apply #'nconc (maplist f x1 ... xn))
```

Also, [`NCONC`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_nconc.htm#nconc) is defined recursively in terms of [`LAST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_last.htm) and [`RPLACD`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm):

```
(nconc) =>  ()
(nconc nil . lists) ==  (nconc . lists)
(nconc list) =>  list
(nconc list-1 list-2) ==  (progn (rplacd (last list-1) list-2) list-1)
(nconc list-1 list-2 . lists) ==  (nconc (nconc list-1 list-2) . lists)
```

An implementation is free to have an efficient implementation for this, provided it computes the same result. But, since it is defined to use `rplacd`, it definitely mutates the list (it links the *cdr* slot of each intermediate result's last cons cell).

Section [§3.7.1 Modification of Literal Objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ga.htm) also says that:

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects are destructively modified.

In your case, you are calling `#'identity` and concatenating destructively values which comes from a quoted list, ie. literal data. The behavior is undefined.

#### Using freshly allocated lists

If, instead of `identity` you call `copy-list`, then each intermediate result is a fresh list and the result is defined:

```
(equalp (apply #'nconc (maplist #'copy-list '(1 2 3)))
        (mapcon #'copy-list '(1 2 3)))
=> T
```

#### Accidental circular lists

If you use non-literal data like `(list 1 2 3)`  the behavior is still undefined, but this is more subtle. For example, let's print the result of `(maplist #'identity (list 1 2 3))` while taking care of circularity:

```
(write (maplist #'identity (list 1 2 3)) :circle t)
```

This prints the following, with [`#n=`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dho.htm) being labels (reader variables) and [`#n#`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhp.htm) back-references to the same lists as previously labeled:

```
((1 . #1=(2 . #2=(3))) #1# #2#)
```

In other words, the result is a list of three lists `(L1 L2 L3)`, where `L2` is the rest of `L1` and `L3` the rest of `L2`. This means that if you do:

```
(apply #'nconc (maplist #'identity (list 1 2 3)))
```

It is as-if you did:

```
(let* ((L1 (list 1 2 3))
       (L2 (rest L1))
       (L3 (rest L2)))
  (nconc L1 L2 L3))
```

Given the above recursive definition, it is equivalent to:

```
(nconc (nconc L1 L2) L3)
^      ^
|      |
|      \-- inner nconc (N1)
|
\-- outer nconc (N0)
```

The inner term *N1* is itself evaluated as:

```
(progn (rplacd (last L1) L2) L1)
```

Here, the end of `L1` is linked to `L2` (the rest of `L1`), which creates a loop. You can try it directly and your environment should print it elided; for example in SBCL:

```
* (setf *print-length* 10)
10

* (let ((L1 (list 1 2 3)))
    (nconc L1 (rest L1)))
(1 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 ...)
```

You could also print it to the REPL by setting `*print-circle*` to T.

That in itself is fine, but then this infinite list is used in the outer invocation of `nconc` named *N0* above. Let's say the intermediate result of evaluating *N1* is `R1`:

```
(nconc R1 L3)
```

The above is evaluated as:

```
(progn (rplacd (last R1) L3) R1)
```

**And here the program is stuck, because `last` never terminates.**

At least, this is the case in most implementations, but note that [`LAST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_last.htm) is defined only when the list is not circular:

> list---a list, which might be a dotted list but must not be a circular list.

That's why the behavior is actually undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon an explanation: "In case of FN results that are *fresh lists (non-sharing)*, the result is same as with (APPLY #'APPEND (MAPLIST ...))." ([Simplified Common Lisp reference](https://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/mapcon.html))

```
(apply #'nconc (maplist #'copy-list '(1 2 3)))
(mapcon #'copy-list '(1 2 3))
```

Funny that this isn't mentioned in the Hyperspec though. Could this have been deduced?